# Do not return data if it already exist in another table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query where if data already exist in one table I don't want it to be returned in this query.

I hope that makes sense, I don't really know how to word it.

Comment: what? what ? you are asking ?

Comment: You should add table schema to the question. Like this you are making it harder to answer a simple question

Comment: no! it is not making sense.

Comment: Chill your beans, I'm new to all this, new job, in training etc

Answer (score 3):

use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLETOCHECK)
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use

```
Columnfromonetable IS NOT IN (SELECT Column from yourtable)
```

For example if you were checking ID's between 2 tables like CustomerID, productID etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` column names it will not return the duplicate column values.

Answer (score 0):

Return all records in TableA that are not in TableB based on a field called ID

```
SELECT a.* FROM TableA a 
Left join TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```